# Attach a WebDriver listener that is triggered on page unload (before navigating to the next page)

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to listen to a page unload event? I'm using the Java WebDriver and have discovered this kind of thing:

```
 webDriver.register(myWebDriverEventListener);
```

Where `org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener` is the interface implemented by *myWebDriverEventListener* in the example above.

The problem is that is has a `beforeNavigateTo` method, but that doesn't get called if a form gets submitted and the URL changes.

The context to my problem - I want a generic way of taking a screenshot just before all form submissions.

Any idea?

Comment: If you used Ruby you would be able to monkeypatch click method so that screenshot will be taken before each click.

Comment: If you want it for debugging you can capture video instead of making screenshots. For example you can use own X11 session for each browser process and capture video from that X11 session. Here is a Ruby gem that does this - https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless. Probably you can do similar in Java.